# How to append to a database table in Matlab

Tags: sql, database, matlab

I am totally new to using databases but I think I can't avoid it. The problem is that I am calculating values through iterations and need to store in some very large matrix to export it as xlsx later.

Since I get errors when I initialize the matrix of that size I wanted to know, how can I create a database, connect to it, create a table, then append the values that I get at every iteration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to be more specific, show what you've already tried, and describe what didn't work. See [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a database, if you just want to do a big matrix? Maybe it's just something like this?

```
% create empty matrix
M = [];
for ii = 1:10
    % replace col1, col2... with your calculations
    col1 = ii^2;
    col2 = ii^3;
    col3 = sqrt(ii);
    % add row to M with new values
    M = [M; col1, col2, col3]; 
end
M
```

what gives

[image: matrix]

You can export your variable M then